# Proving Beltrami-Enneper theorem

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

#### Preamble

I am trying to prove the Beltrami-Enneper theorem, which states that, given an assymptotic curve $\alpha$ in a surface $S$ that has non-zero curvature everywhere obeys that:

$|\tau| = \sqrt{-K}$

Where $\tau$ is the torsion and $K$ is the Gaussian curvature.

The conventions in the notation are $N$ is the normal to the surface $T_\alpha, N_\alpha, B_\alpha$ are thr tangent normal and binormal to the curve. $k_1, k_2$ are the principal curvatures of the surface at the evaluated point. $k$ is used to denote curvature.

So far I have this:

#### My Work

The curve $\alpha$ is an assymptotic curve, which means that at $P \in \alpha$ the normal curvature is 0, so:

$\langle N, kN_\alpha \rangle  = 0$

$N$ is a unit length vector orthogonal to $T_\alpha$ and $N_\alpha$ the tangent and normal vectors to the curve, so:

$N = T_\alpha \times N_\alpha = B_\alpha \iff N' = \tau N_\alpha$.

So $N'\cdot N' = \tau^2$.

By Euler's theorem: $k_n = \langle dN_p(v), v \rangle = k_1\cos^2(\theta) + k_2\sin^2(\theta)$

#### Cheat

This is where I am getting stuck, I took a sneak peak at the solution and it states that:

$|N'^2| = k_1^2\cos^2(\theta) + k_2^2\sin^2(\theta)$ Where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent to the curve and $e_1$ the first principal direction.

I don't know how that above relationship was derived, I am looking for the proof that indeed:
$|N'^2| = k_1^2\cos^2(\theta) + k_2^2\sin^2(\theta)$

As I failed to derive it on my own.

#### Solution (with doubt)

I managed to finish the proof by leveraging something I saw in the proof for Euler's theorem:

By Euler's theorem: $k_n = \langle dN_p(v), v \rangle = k_1\cos^2(\theta) + k_2\sin^2(\theta)$. But more importantly:
$dN_p(v) = k_1e_1\cos(\theta) + k_2e_2\sin(\theta)$

So $N'\cdot N' = k_1^2\cos^2(\theta) + k_2^2\sin^2(\theta)$

By the fact the curve is assymptotic we get $N\cdot N_\alpha = 0 = k_1\cos^2(\theta) + k_2\sin^2(\theta)$

So $\cos^2(\theta) = -k_2\sin^2(\theta) / k_1$ and $\sin^2(\theta) = -k_1\cos^2(\theta) / k_2$.

And thus:

$N'\cdot N' = k_1^2\frac{-k_2\sin^2(\theta)}{k_1} + k_2^2\frac{k_1\cos^2(\theta)}{k_2} = k_1k_2\sin^2(\theta) + -k_1k_2\cos^2(\theta) = -k_1k_2$

So $\tau^2 = -k_1k_2$

I am still however not satisfied with my work, because I have no idea why this holds:
$$dN_p(v) = k_1e_1\cos(\theta) + k_2e_2\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Enneper!!  The formula you're referring to is called Euler's formula. It's standard in textbooks. You can find it in my differential geometry text, in case you have not yet downloaded and looked at it.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the correction, however there is a small difference between Euler's theorem and the hint. Euler's formula stats $k_1\cos^1 + k_2\sin^2$ hoever in teh hints formula, the curvatures are squared as well. So it's not a direct application of Euler's theorem, there's some small additinal detail that explains why the principal curvatures are also being squared.

Comment: HINT The normal curvature vanishes for the asymptotic line. $ k_1  \cos^2 \theta + k_2  \sin^2 \theta + =0 $$

Comment: It's still about *understanding* where Euler comes from. If $e_1,e_2$ are the principal directions, then the  derivative of $N$ in the direction of the asymptotic curve is $N'=(k_1\cos\theta)e_1 + (k_2\sin\theta)e_2$, is it not?

Comment: @TedShifrin You are correct, this is part of the prrof for euler's theorem in Do Carmo's book, I am trying to understand that fact right now. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Use the fact that $dN_p$ is a linear map.